# Is there a procedure in place to refer people to professional help

Tags: discussion

I've noticed posts on suicide, abuse, potentially dangerous situations, lovelorn questions, and some posts referring to behavior where professionals should be called in ASAP.

Should these questions be shut down quickly and are there resources we know of which may be of service to these people that we have on file, can link to or recommend to people in such situations?

Comment: Not an answer, but related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2847/11659

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243701/316226

Comment: Maybe this can help, seems to be related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348/455 and the top answer has links too

Answer (score 1):

I think the policy if e.g. someone is suicidal is to reach an SE "Community Moderator" (an SE employee) -- see e.g. [this post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6258/19237) from 2013.

As well as using "Contact Us", see also [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/whats-the-official-se-response-to-serious-mentions-of-suicide-or-self-harm-in-p#comment806660_243701):

> One minor addendum: a moderator facing #3 should contact a CM directly in chat if at all possible. Do not worry about "bothering" them for something like this. Most mods will already know this, but for the benefit of new mods (of which there always seem to be a few 'cause SE is healthy and growing), it's probably worth a mention.